# Display latest posts from a specific tag in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, posts

I am trying to alter my Wordpress theme to display the latest posts from a specific tag. It currently lists the latest posts overall.

Here is part of the code that it uses:

```
<?php
    if ( is_home() ) {
        $args=array(
            'showposts'=> (int) get_option('aggregate_homepage_posts'),
            'paged'=>$paged,
            'category__not_in' => (array) get_option('aggregate_exlcats_recent')
        );
        if (get_option('aggregate_duplicate') == 'false') {
            global $ids;
            $args['post__not_in'] = $ids;
        }
        query_posts($args);
        global $paged;
    }
    $i = 0;
?>
<?php 
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php
        $i++;
        $et_is_latest_post = ( $paged == 0 && ( is_home() && $i <= 2 ) ) || !is_home();
    ?>
        <div class="post entry clearfix<?php if ( $et_is_latest_post ) echo ' latest'; ?>">
            <?php
                $thumb = '';
                $width = $et_is_latest_post ? 170 : 67;
                $height = $et_is_latest_post ? 110 : 67;
                $classtext = 'post-thumb';
                $titletext = get_the_title();
                $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,$classtext,$titletext,$titletext,false,'Entry');
                $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];
            ?>

            <?php if($thumb <> '' && get_option('aggregate_thumbnails_index') == 'on') { ?>
                <div class="thumb thumbcont">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, $classtext); ?>
                        <span class="overlay"></span>
                    </a>
<a class="thumb<?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->category_nicename; ?>" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/<?php echo $category[0]->category_nicename; ?>"><?php echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></a>
                </div>  <!-- end .post-thumbnail -->

            <?php } ?>

            <h3 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php get_template_part('includes/postinfo'); ?>

            <p class="postsummery">
            <?php
              $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
              echo string_limit_words($excerpt,20);
            ?>
            </p>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="more"><span><?php esc_html_e('Read More','Aggregate'); ?></span></a>
        </div>  <!-- end .post-->
<?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); }
    else { ?>
         <?php get_template_part('includes/navigation','entry'); ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part('includes/no-results','entry'); ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

While doing some research, I found some details of how to do this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

However, my very limited knowledge of PHP coding and lack of understanding how my current code works with the examples provided, I cannot find a way to do it. Can you guide me?

Comment: you simple add `'tag'=>the tag u wanted listed,` after array( at line3

Comment: Can you please be more specific with your idea, how would I do this? Do I add **'tag'=>hello** if my tag is hello?

Comment: @Breezer Just tried it and it worked perfectly! Can you please make an answer to this question and I will mark it as correct. This will give you a few points for your effort ;) Tack!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simple add 'tag'=>the tag u wanted listed, after array( at line3
why well cause that's the array containing the arguments that then will be passed to the get posts function that makes a call to the database, the arguments that you got to choose from can be find here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters
And the full code would look like so

```
   <?php
    if ( is_home() ) {
        $args=array(
            'showposts'=> (int) get_option('aggregate_homepage_posts'),
            'paged'=>$paged,
            'tag'=>"the tag u want shown",
            'category__not_in' => (array) get_option('aggregate_exlcats_recent')
        );
        if (get_option('aggregate_duplicate') == 'false') {
            global $ids;
            $args['post__not_in'] = $ids;
        }
        query_posts($args);
        global $paged;
    }
    $i = 0;
?>
<?php 
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php
        $i++;
        $et_is_latest_post = ( $paged == 0 && ( is_home() && $i <= 2 ) ) || !is_home();
    ?>
        <div class="post entry clearfix<?php if ( $et_is_latest_post ) echo ' latest'; ?>">
            <?php
                $thumb = '';
                $width = $et_is_latest_post ? 170 : 67;
                $height = $et_is_latest_post ? 110 : 67;
                $classtext = 'post-thumb';
                $titletext = get_the_title();
                $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,$classtext,$titletext,$titletext,false,'Entry');
                $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];
            ?>

            <?php if($thumb <> '' && get_option('aggregate_thumbnails_index') == 'on') { ?>
                <div class="thumb thumbcont">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, $classtext); ?>
                        <span class="overlay"></span>
                    </a>
<a class="thumb<?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->category_nicename; ?>" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/<?php echo $category[0]->category_nicename; ?>"><?php echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></a>
                </div>  <!-- end .post-thumbnail -->

            <?php } ?>

            <h3 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php get_template_part('includes/postinfo'); ?>

            <p class="postsummery">
            <?php
              $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
              echo string_limit_words($excerpt,20);
            ?>
            </p>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="more"><span><?php esc_html_e('Read More','Aggregate'); ?></span></a>
        </div>  <!-- end .post-->
<?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); }
    else { ?>
         <?php get_template_part('includes/navigation','entry'); ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part('includes/no-results','entry'); ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```